# Make Canvas Cover up Button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that has a link when clicked, but the canvas does not cover up the entire button. How can I do this? This is my canvas:

```js
//Lets create a simple particle system in HTML5 canvas and JS

//Initializing the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//Canvas dimensions
var W = 500; var H = 500;

//Lets create an array of particles
var particles = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
 //This will add 50 particles to the array with random positions
 particles.push(new create_particle());
}

//Lets create a function which will help us to create multiple particles
function create_particle()
{
 //Random position on the canvas
 this.x = Math.random()*W;
 this.y = Math.random()*H;
 
 //Lets add random velocity to each particle
 this.vx = Math.random()*20-10;
 this.vy = Math.random()*20-10;
 
 //Random colors
 var r = Math.random()*255>>0;
 var g = Math.random()*255>>0;
 var b = Math.random()*255>>0;
 this.color = "rgba("+r+", "+g+", "+b+", 0.5)";
 
 //Random size
 this.radius = Math.random()*10+10;
}

var x = 100; var y = 100;

//Lets animate the particle
function draw()
{
 //Moving this BG paint code insde draw() will help remove the trail
 //of the particle
 //Lets paint the canvas black
 //But the BG paint shouldn't blend with the previous frame
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
 //Lets reduce the opacity of the BG paint to give the final touch
 ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
 
 //Lets blend the particle with the BG
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
 
 //Lets draw particles from the array now
 for(var t = 0; t < particles.length; t++)
 {
  var p = particles[t];
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  
  //Time for some colors
  var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(p.x, p.y, 0, p.x, p.y, p.radius);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.4, "white");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.4, p.color);
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");
  
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, Math.PI*2, false);
  ctx.fill();
  
  //Lets use the velocity now
  p.x += p.vx;
  p.y += p.vy;
  
  //To prevent the balls from moving out of the canvas
  if(p.x < -50) p.x = W+50;
  if(p.y < -50) p.y = H+50;
  if(p.x > W+50) p.x = -50;
  if(p.y > H+50) p.y = -50;
 }
}

setInterval(draw, 33);
//I hope that you enjoyed the tutorial :)
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
}

#submit {
  position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 15%;
 margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button align=center>
  <canvas width="100" height="25" id="canvas"></canvas>
  <span id="submit">Submit</span>
</button>
```

I would think you would change the width and height of the button, but I'm not sure. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your button's height is more than the canvas height. And also there is some padding along with border for the button and also different browsers may have different button height being rendered as you have not provided any height to the button so you need to make the button of the same height as the canvas i.e `height: 25px;` and remove the padding and border from the button. Below is the code. Hope it helps

```js
//Lets create a simple particle system in HTML5 canvas and JS

//Initializing the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//Canvas dimensions
var W = 500; var H = 500;

//Lets create an array of particles
var particles = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
 //This will add 50 particles to the array with random positions
 particles.push(new create_particle());
}

//Lets create a function which will help us to create multiple particles
function create_particle()
{
 //Random position on the canvas
 this.x = Math.random()*W;
 this.y = Math.random()*H;
 
 //Lets add random velocity to each particle
 this.vx = Math.random()*20-10;
 this.vy = Math.random()*20-10;
 
 //Random colors
 var r = Math.random()*255>>0;
 var g = Math.random()*255>>0;
 var b = Math.random()*255>>0;
 this.color = "rgba("+r+", "+g+", "+b+", 0.5)";
 
 //Random size
 this.radius = Math.random()*10+10;
}

var x = 100; var y = 100;

//Lets animate the particle
function draw()
{
 //Moving this BG paint code insde draw() will help remove the trail
 //of the particle
 //Lets paint the canvas black
 //But the BG paint shouldn't blend with the previous frame
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
 //Lets reduce the opacity of the BG paint to give the final touch
 ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
 
 //Lets blend the particle with the BG
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
 
 //Lets draw particles from the array now
 for(var t = 0; t < particles.length; t++)
 {
  var p = particles[t];
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  
  //Time for some colors
  var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(p.x, p.y, 0, p.x, p.y, p.radius);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.4, "white");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.4, p.color);
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");
  
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, Math.PI*2, false);
  ctx.fill();
  
  //Lets use the velocity now
  p.x += p.vx;
  p.y += p.vy;
  
  //To prevent the balls from moving out of the canvas
  if(p.x < -50) p.x = W+50;
  if(p.y < -50) p.y = H+50;
  if(p.x > W+50) p.x = -50;
  if(p.y > H+50) p.y = -50;
 }
}

setInterval(draw, 33);
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;

}
button {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin:0px;
  height:25px;
}


#submit {
  position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 15%;
 margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button align=center>
  <canvas width="100" height="25" id="canvas"></canvas>
  <span id="submit">Submit</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Why is it not aligning to center?

Comment: as i have mentioned different browsers have different rendering. So if you are not providing style of your own, browser will automatically render the button  according to its own defaults. Hence it wont align to center.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your button element has padding and a border.

Add this to your css:

```
button {
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
}
```

You will also get a small bar at the bottom of the button on some browsers in this situation, so you might need to set the height of the button to a static number like `height: 25px;`

Here is the js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wgsge7b9/